# Creating classes and IBOutlets in Interface Builder (XCode 3.2.3)

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xcode3.2

I normally create classes and IBOutlets in XCode. However I saw a video where someone created a class and the IBOutlets in Interface Builder and the files and outlets were automatically inserted into the source code seen from XCode. They were using an older version of XCode. I tried doing this, but when I went back to XCode, I didn't see any IBOutlets. How can this be done with XCode 3.2.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlets and Actions have been moved into the Library window.  Select the Classes tab, then select your class, and in the dropdown in the bottom half of the window, select Outlets.

EDIT:  Sorry, missed that 2nd to last sentence.  After adding them, save the file and do File > "Write Class Files" I believe.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But the problem is when I go into XCode I don't see the results.

Answer (score 1):

Phenom you should look at the bottom of your project files below the products folder.